# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Tags: error, registry, object

how to solve this problem

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in `F:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\company\module\Block\Customer\Sales\Order\View\block.php` on line 18

my php:

```
public function getOrder() {
    return Mage::registry('current_order');
}

public function getBackUrl() {
    return Mage::getUrl('sales/order/view',array('order_id' =>$this->getOrder()->getId())); 
}
```

Comment: It's pretty apparent that there is no 'current_order' in registry. Is the company/module controller meant to be setting this value, or is this hooking into vanilla magento functionality?

Answer (score 2):

This Registry variable did not have object.You need to check the object:

```
public function getOrder() {
    if(Mage::registry('current_order')){
     return Mage::registry('current_order');
}
retrun false;
}

public function getBackUrl() {
if($this->getOrder()){
    return Mage::getUrl('sales/order/view',array('order_id' =>$this->getOrder()->getId())); 
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: This would probablt cause the same error als getId would be called on a variable containing false. The check should be done were getId is called